# SwiftUI animation with switch statement

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, watchos

I understand how simple animations work in SwiftUI. However, I have a slightly more complex watchOS application. View state is handled by a `switch` statement:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var state: AppState

    @State private var selection = 1

    var body: some View {
        Group {
            switch state.view {
            case .start:
                TabView(selection: $selection) {
                    ActivityView()
                        .tag(0)
                    StartView()
                        .tag(1)
                    SettingsView()
                        .tag(2)
                }
            case .workout:
                TabView(selection: $selection) {
                    TakeoffControlView()
                        .tag(0)
                    TakeoffView()
                        .tag(1)
                }
            }

            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

In another view I edit the view state:

```swift
struct StartView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var state: AppState

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            state.view = .workout
        }, label: {
            Text("Start")
        })
    }
}
```

How can I add animations to transition between the different cases? I tried adding an animation to the `Group`, `TabView` and individual views without success. Obviously I wrapped the state change in `withAnimation`. However, I wasn't able to make it work. Any ideas how to make this work?

Comment: if possible , please add reproducible code !

Answer (score 7):

`.transition()` is just defining what the transition is , and to get the expected transition animation , you have to do the changes to `SourceOfTruth` inside `withAnimation() { ... }` block.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var state: AppState

    @State private var selection = 1

    var body: some View {
        Group {
            switch state.view {
            case .start:
                TabView(selection: $selection) {
                    ActivityView()
                        .tag(0)
                    StartView()
                        .tag(1)
                    SettingsView()
                        .tag(2)
                }
                .transition(.slide)//<- here
                
            case .workout:
                TabView(selection: $selection) {
                    TakeoffControlView()
                        .tag(0)
                    TakeoffView()
                        .tag(1)
                }
                .transition(.slide)//<- here
            }

            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

```swift
struct StartView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var state: AppState

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            withAnimation(.easeIn) {  //<- here
                state.view = .workout
            }
        }, label: {
            Text("Start")
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: But you can't always put your action logic in a `Button` closure. Sometimes `state.view = .workout` comes inside a view model, etc. It would be nice if you could just put the transition logic near the switch statement.

Comment: @flopshot If you add the withAnimation in your vm it will still work.

Comment: Thank you very much! Exactly what I was looking for. Tip for anyone thinking this doesn't work: You have to run it in the simulator, apparently animations don't work for the live preview